# Executing multiple queries, characters found after end of sql statement

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, ms-access-2013

I am trying to execute two queries as given below but its giving me characters found after end of sql statement exception. I intend to add some data in table2 from table1 and some from the user. The database used is ms access database.

```
try{
     String ad=  ((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
     String dd= ((JTextField)jDateChooser2.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
     String rt= jTextField8.getText();
     int rn= Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
     int rr= Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
     String sr= jTextField7.getText();
     int nn= Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText());
     int na= Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText());
     int nc= Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText());
     int gc= Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());

     stmt= conn.createStatement();
     String squery="insert into Room(GuestCode, Title, FirstName, LastName, Country, State, City, ContactNo) select GuestCode, Title, FirstName, LastName, Country, State, City, ContactNo from GuestDetails where GuestCode=gc;insert into Room(ArrivalDate, DepartureDate, RoomType, RoomNo, RoomRate, SpecialRequirements, NoOfNights, NoOfAdults, NoOfChildren) values(' "+ad+" ',' "+dd+" ',' "+rt+" ',' "+rn+" ',' "+rr+" ',' "+sr+" ',' "+nn+" ',' "+na+" ',' "+nc+" ');";

     rs=stmt.executeQuery(squery);
 }catch(Exception ex){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
 }
```

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` (in addition to following Joris' advice).

Comment: Be a responsible programmer. Avoid SQL injections while writing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allowed to put more than one statement into stmt.executeQuery, so everything after the ; (and you can leave the ; out too) should be put in a separate query and executed separately.

However on reading your problem description again (and when starting to edit to add prepared statements) I've figured out that what you try to do is retrieve some data from 1 source and the remainder from the variables in your scope.

You can only use 1 insert to insert data. if you use multiple, they will end up as multiple rows.
If you insist on using 2 statements, 1 should be an insert, the other an update. (still run 2 separate executeQuery's to run them.)

If you want to do it in 1 statement then you will have to write your query in such a way that it will work like that.

this then looks like a duplicate of:
[Using INSERT INTO with 'SELECT' to supply some values but not others (Access 2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757348/using-insert-into-with-select-to-supply-some-values-but-not-others-access-201)

lastly: try using prepared statements to avoid sql injection (and making much tidier code)

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("select abc from xyz where x = ?");
statement.setString(1, "value you want to match x with";
statement.executeQuery();

// this will replace the value of the first ? with "value you want to match x with"
```

Comment: please edit your answer to recommend using `PreparedStatement` to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: I tried using prepared statement too but getting the same exception. Also I am new to java and sql so can you please elaborate

Comment: Yeah good point, I was just focussing on his immediate issue but that is rather important as well.

Comment: @pallavi , first split it into 2 statements (so String query1 = ... and String query 2 = ... ) and execute those separately.  then _also_ use prepared statements as they are a better and safer way to run sql. I'll update my answer with an example