# How to select top 1 ID from each of two not joinable tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I got an n to n relation on my db and want to now fill up the connecting table in the middle.

I have the same issue as [that guy here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172465/query-input-must-contain-at-least-one-table-or-query-error), but my two tables are not directly related.

So my first try was:

```
INSERT into foo_has_bar (foo_ID, bar_ID) VALUES (
  (Select TOP 1 ID from foo where foo_cond = "TRUE"),
  (Select TOP 1 ID from bar where bar_cond = "TRUE")
)
```

Now this is invalid and returns

> Query input must contain at least one table or query

When now trying to create it in the form as described in the link above I would need something like this:

```
INSERT into foo_has_bar (foo_ID, bar_ID)
Select foo.ID, bar.ID FROM foo, bar
...
)
```

But how can I now *merge* the `SELECT TOP 1` for each of those and the `WHERE` also only for the corresponding (`foo`wont have a `bar_cond`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual solution I found through the hints in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757348/using-insert-into-with-select-to-supply-some-values-but-not-others-access-201):

```
INSERT into foo_has_bar (foo_ID, bar_ID)
VALUES (DLOOKUP("ID", "foo", "foo_cond = ""TRUE"""),
        (DLOOKUP("ID", "bar", "bar_cond = ""TRUE"""),
       );
```

*Awful escaping in ACCESS*..

Answer (score 2):

I would expect this query to work in MS Access:

```
INSERT into foo_has_bar (foo_ID, bar_ID)
    VALUES ((Select TOP 1 ID from foo where foo_cond = "TRUE"),
            (Select TOP 1 ID from bar where bar_cond = "TRUE")
           );
```

But if it doesn't, try this:

```
INSERT into foo_has_bar (foo_ID, bar_ID)
    SELECT f.ID, b.ID
    FROM (Select TOP 1 ID from foo where foo_cond = "TRUE"
         ) as f,
         (Select TOP 1 ID from bar where bar_cond = "TRUE"
         ) as b;
```

As a note:  Normally you should use `ORDER BY` with `TOP`, so which id you get is consistent.