# Passing a string variable in SQL query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to write a SQL query that takes in WHERE conditional value from a variable.

The variable is a string type and it is being extracted first from a different table using a different query through the use of recordsets. I think I got the quotations right in the query but it shows "Undefined function 'rsDB' in expression" error.

```
extPMBActID_SQL = "SELECT * FROM PMB;"
Set rsDB = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(extPMBActID_SQL, dbOpenDynaset)
testID = Left(rsDB.Fields("ActivityID"), 2)
instRptGen_SQL = "SELECT AreaName FROM Area WHERE AreaID =" & "Left(rsDB.Fields('ActivityID'), 2)" & ";"
Set rsDB = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(instRptGen_SQL, dbOpenDynaset)
```

I think whenever the query is ran, it is somehow not able to fetch `rsDB.Fields("ActivityID")` value. I am sure that `testID` variable does have the value.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes from that second part:

```
instRptGen_SQL = "SELECT AreaName FROM Area WHERE AreaID =" & _
            Left(rsDB.Fields("ActivityID").Value, 2)
```

You don't need the terminating `;`, and if AreaID is not numeric you need single quotes around the value:

```
instRptGen_SQL = "SELECT AreaName FROM Area WHERE AreaID ='" & _
            Left(rsDB.Fields("ActivityID").Value, 2) & "'"
```

Comment: I did try this a whle ago and it throws me data type mismatch error... The ```Left(rsDB...``` is a string so I am guessing it needs to in quotes. I might be wrong...

Comment: Do you think I can pass a SELECT query into Values parameter of ```INSERT INTO``` statement? I built a query that looks something like this:


```instRptGen_SQL = "INSERT INTO testTable (ID, arbName) VALUES(Left(rsDB('ActivityID'), 2), 'SELECT AreaName FROM Area WHERE AreaID =' & Left(rs.Fields('ActivityID'), 2))"```


It is giving me invalid operation error..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757348/using-insert-into-with-select-to-supply-some-values-but-not-others-access-201