Microsoft Access SQL is clipping a string when using INSERT to add a record
I have developed a VBA subroutine to merge a set of similar tables, filter records and do some data cleansing to produce a single table of graduation results.  One field is a string containing a date value [Board Date] typically in the format "1 January 1901".  When the value is inserted into the database using SQL INSERT, it is being clipped to the first 10 characters.  The field is a Short Text field in the database, as are most of the entries.  None of the other Short Text fields are being clipped.
For context, I am holding the date as a string because not all source tables have valid date entries.  I want to preserve the data so not all entries into this field will be valid dates.
The version of Access being used is Microsoft Access for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2402 Build 16.0.17328.20550) 64-bit.
The table definition looks like this:

The line to import the data is:
sql = "INSERT INTO [All Awards] ([ID], [Surname], [Forename], [D-o-b], [Sex], [Hold], [AOS Code], [Year], [Academic Period], " & _
    "[Award Type], [Award Title], [Comb stud a], [Comb stud b], [Emphasis], [In], [Hons], [Classification], [Board Date], [Research Title], " & _
    "[D-o-b Error], [Board Date Error]) VALUES (""" & _
    id_val & """,""" & _
    surname_val & """,""" & _
    forename_val & """,""" & _
    dob_val & """,""" & _
    sex_val & """,""" & _
    hold_val & """,""" & _
    aos_code_val & """,""" & _
    year_val & """,""" & _
    academic_period_val & """,""" & _
    award_type_val & """,""" & _
    award_title_val & """,""" & _
    comb_stud_a_val & """,""" & _
    comb_stud_b_val & """,""" & _
    emphasis_val & """,""" & _
    in_val & """,""" & _
    hons_val & """,""" & _
    class_val & """,""" & _
    board_date_val & """,""" & _
    res_title_val & """," & _
    dob_error & "," & _
    board_date_error & _
    ");"
    Debug.Print sql                    
    DoCmd.RunSQL sql

The debug printout of the SQL command is:
INSERT INTO [All Awards] ([ID], [Surname], [Forename], [D-o-b], [Sex], [Hold], [AOS Code], [Year], [Academic Period], [Award Type], [Award Title], [Comb stud a], [Comb stud b], [Emphasis], [In], [Hons], [Classification], [Board Date], [Research Title], [D-o-b Error], [Board Date Error]) VALUES ("1234567","Beta","Albert","01/01/1901","M","","190","3","93/94","DOCTOR OF PHILOSOPHY","","","","","","","","01 October 1994","Research title.", False, False);

As you can see, the [Board Date] ("01 October 1994") is intact at this point.
The imported date string in the table looks like this:

At this point, the field has been clipped to the first 10 characters.  There are no characters (spaces, etc.) after "01 October".
Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to fix it?

I have fixed the problem by changing the field to a Long Text type, but this doesn't explain why this field is clipped and other Short Text fields aren't.  I would still be interested to know why this is happening if anyone has an explanation.

I believe (others may disagree) that this is one of MS Access' many bugs. You may find this doesn't happen if your data sits within something like an MS SQL database with your VBA/Front end forms pointing at that, rather than holding the data within Access.

Ok, good to know.  Thanks.  If no-one comes up with anything better/different in a couple of days then post that as the answer and I will accept it.

What's the length setting of that field? I'd be hesitant to dismiss this as "undefined bugs", while there are some documented bugs a plain insert should certainly work, as long as that content fits in the field length.

Short Text columns have a Field Size property with a value range of 0 .. 255 along with other important properties like Required and Default Value and many more.

Your "fix" is not the fix; the length of the field is too short or something else is going on. There is not bug here as Access, of course, can store a short string. Also, don't store dates as text, always use Date.

I MS Access, text type of data should be within single quote ['] and date type of data should be within number/hash sign [#].  You made some compromise with date type of field by converted it to short text, no need.
Your INSERT SQL statement is good enough. Just replace the double quote ["] with single quote ['] in short text field and number [#] in date type of fields.

What is the SIZE property of that specific short text field ?

Why don't you simply use an INSERT SELECT instead of VALUES ?? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17757401/78522

[What is the SIZE property of that specific short text field ? – iDevlop Commented18 mins ago]
The size if 50.

[Why don't you simply use an INSERT SELECT instead of VALUES ?? See stackoverflow.com/a/17757401/78522 – iDevlop Commented17 mins ago]
Because I have to do some data cleansing on the source data.

Annoyingly, I have reverted the field to a Short Text to test the single quote suggestion above.  I re-ran my code without making any changes and the [Board Date] values are all correct now and not being truncated.  This does lend some credence to the view that it might be a bug.

Maybe it had a size of 10 before those changes. But, a mentioned by others, store the date in a Date/Time field! Otherwise you will get troubles on PCs having different culture settings. If you think that a Date field has a wrong format, then set the Format property of the field accordingly. As Text you will not be able to order the rows by date or to search for a specific date range.

On the date point, I am constructing the date from separate day, month and year fields in a legacy database.  The aim is to find any legacy records that didn't make it into an old Access DB.  I will be migrating missing the records into that DB.  The dates in that DB are stored as text so I am storing mine as text to make the migration easy.  That database is over 10 years old and I am following an "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" approach.

And, in all honesty, the "store it as a date" response doesn't address the original problem.  It's irrelevant that it happens to be a date.  It could be any text.  The issue is that it was being truncated when it should not be, not that it happens to be a string of date information.

[I MS Access, text type of data should be within single quote ['] and date type of data should be within number/hash sign [#].]
So... I changed the code so that it uses single quotes throughout for strings and it works fine and the [Board Date] field isn't truncated.  As I noted about half an hour ago, I changed the field back to a Short Text and ran my code with double quotes and that also worked, so I am not sure if we have proved anything here.  Anyway, my code works for now, which is the main thing.

The short answer to my question is probably "user error" or "user ignorance".  The slightly longer answer is that I have inadvertently changed the SIZE parameter for the Short Text fields and this is leading to entered values being truncated.  If this happens to you then check the SIZE parameter in the table design view for the given field.  Thanks to Erik A and iDevelop for steering me in that direction.
I did a little bit of an experiment with a new blank database and found the following:
If you create a new Short Text field it will default to 255 characters.  If, in the current session, you change that field to a Long Text, save the database, and then change it back to a Short Text, it will revert to being 255 characters long.  The image below shows the "after" view of this change.

However, the behaviour is different if you make this change across multiple sessions.  First, I changed a Short Text field to a Long Text, saved the database and closed it.  I then re-opened the database and changed the field back to a Short Text.  In this case, it changed to being 50 characters long, not 255.  The image below shows the "after" view of this change.

This doesn't explain why my field was set to 2 characters, hence the explanation of user error, but I think it is worth noting that Short Text field sizes can change in a counter-intuitive way if you are making changes to the database design across sessions.

Summarizing the comments into an answer. While Short Text is the field type chosen for this column, that field type has a setting of Field Size that generally defaults to 50. Likely that default was changed in the original version of your table.
You changed the field type to Long Text and the SQL worked as expected. Changing the field type back to Short Text likely caused it to pick up the default Field Size of 50 once again. This is why both your single and double quote attempts worked successfully.
For folks that may stumble into this question in the future with the similar problem, here is a screenshot of the settings available for the Short Text field type:


Just out of interest, how would the field size get changed?  I didn't know that this was possible so I haven't changed it.  I started this project with a new database, which presumably would have had the default sizes for the fields?

Perhaps accidentally? There's a few ways to change that using the UI or an SQL ALTER command. While you are using a pretty new version, I think it's unlikely given the MASSIVE usage of MS Access that you are lucky enough to be the first to stumble onto a bug that would be this big and obvious.

I suspect there is something going on under the hood that neither of us understands.  I have checked online (and created a scratch DB) and the default size for Short Text is 255.  I checked my remaining Short Text fields and they are kinds of sizes, mostly around the size of the data in them, e.g. [Sex] is 1 (M or F), but not all which is odd.  I have only used INSERT and UPDATE commands on the DB via VBA and am not so ham-fisted that I could change all those fields sizes in the UI without realising.  Anyway, that will have to be a mystery for another day.  It works now, and that's all I need.

Did you create your table via the UI or through an import or linked database or some other means? I suspect maybe if it was through a CSV import, for instance, than the Jet/Ace engine will likely make decisions on the field type based on the first N records in the file. That could very well leave it guessing CHAR(10) if those first N records in the file were under that limit.

Consider the SQL best practice of parameterization and avoid using any embedded quotations and variable concatenation. MS Access supports parameters with QueryDefs. However, DAO parameters do not accommodate text parameters  more than 255 characters. However, ADO Command does.
Dim sql As String, var As Variant
Dim cmd As Object

' SQL WITH QMARK ? PLACEHOLDERS 
sql = "INSERT INTO [All Awards] ( " & _
   "  [ID], [Surname], [Forename], [D-o-b], [Sex], " & _
   "  [Hold], [AOS Code], [Year], [Academic Period], " & _
   "  [Award Type], [Emphasis], [In], " & _
   "  [Hons], [Classification], [Board Date], " & _
   "  [Award Title], [Research Title]," & _
   "  [Comb stud a], [Comb stud b]," & _
   "  [D-o-b Error], [Board Date Error]" & _
   ") VALUES (" & _
   "   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?," & _
   "   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?" & _
   ");"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
    .CommandText = sql
  
    ' APPEND VARCHAR PARAMETERS
    For Each var in Array( _
       id_val, surname_val, forename_val, dob_val, sex_val, _
       hold_val, aos_code_val, year_val, academic_period_val, award_type_val, _
       emphasis_val, in_val, hons_val, class_val, board_date_val, _
       award_title_val, res_title_val, comb_stud_a_val, comb_stud_b_val
    )
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, , var)
    Next var

    ' APPEND DATE PARAMETERS 
    For Each var in Array(dob_error, board_date_error)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput, , var)
    Next var

   ' EXECUTE ACTION
   .Execute
End With

Set cmd = Nothing

